# node js async request cant get body of web page

Tags: node.js, async-await, httprequest, fetch

I want to get the body of web-page from a list of more than 1000 urls (my goal is to do scraping using cheerio then).
**The problem is that I get a weird GUNZIP result** and I can't get the content of the body tag. This is the code that I'm using (**I cant use a simple "request" cause it misses some request**)

```
var async = require('async');
var fetch = require('isomorphic-unfetch');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let urls= // reading a list of ~1000 URLs from JSON file

async.mapLimit(urls, 1, async function(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.body
}, (err, results) => {
     if (err) throw err
     console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I think more info is required. What is a weird gunzip result for example? Is this for all, or just one URL? Could it be related to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148948/how-do-i-ungzip-decompress-a-nodejs-requests-module-gzip-response-body)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I get a weird GUNZIP result

use zlib,

```
var zlib = require('zlib');


async.mapLimit(urls, 1, async function(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  zlib.gunzip(response.body, function(err, dezipped) {
      return (dezipped.toString());
  });
}, (err, results) => {
     if (err) throw err
     console.log(results);
});
```

then purseed your parsing with cheerio :)

i hope this helps.