# how to get a json file from another domain in with node request?

Tags: json, node.js, utf-8, utf8-decode, node-request

I have a json file in remote server. `<domainName>/info.json`. When I navigate to the url I get:

```
{
  "version": "1.8 RC05"
}
```

But when I do `curl <domainname>/info.json` from my terminal, I get something like:

```
�T*K-*�RP2Գr60Uk�%�c9@
```

When I use node `request` as follows:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    request.get('<domainname>/info.json').on('response', function(data){
        data = data.setEncoding('utf8');
        console.log(data.statusCode);
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I get the following response:

```
     {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application\/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "46",
        "connection": "close",
        "date": "Tue, 22 Sep 2015 09:56:22 GMT",
        "content-encoding": "gzip",
        "cache-control": "max-age=1800, public",
        "last-modified": "Mon, 21 Sep 2015 09:57:35 GMT",
        "etag": "\"93934d435cecbf8f5bde8627903587a0\"",
        "server": "AmazonS3",
        "age": "903",
        "x-cache": "Hit from cloudfront",
        "via": "1.1 44e39d55d481d0cc2faa76f70b7a556b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "x-amz-cf-id": "eOy_rb3vasUnhb9bvvKI3AZvcvXAzJeJCI3TmK94ZlaxHu1XwBKzGg=="
      },
      "request": {
        "uri": {
          "protocol": "https:",
          "slashes": true,
          "auth": null,
          "host": "<domainname>",
          "port": 443,
          "hostname": "<domainname>",
          "hash": null,
          "search": null,
          "query": null,
          "pathname": "\/info.json",
          "path": "\/info.json",
          "href": "<domainname>\/info.json"
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {

        }
      }
    }
```

I think it has to do something with `charset=utf-8`, but dont know how to proceed. How do I make my node app get the first json object and serve it?

**EDIT 1**

As suggested in the answer I served the body as follows:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    request('<domainname>/info.json', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
      }
    });
});
```

Now I get following response:

```
"\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003���T*K-*���S�RP2ԳP\br60U��\u0005\u0000k�%�\u001a\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Node Request Docs](https://github.com/request/request).

You probably want to be sending the `body`, not the whole `response`:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    request('<domainname>/info.json', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
      }
    })
});
```

You also probably want to gzip/decompress the response.

For this you can use [Nodes Zlib implementation](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html)

You can see an exmaple of its use here [How do I ungzip (decompress) a NodeJS request's module gzip response body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148948/how-do-i-ungzip-decompress-a-nodejs-requests-module-gzip-response-body)

Comment: okay, so we have one problem down on the response part. but I am still getting `���T*K-*���S�RP2Գr60U��k�%�`  served.

Comment: in the browser, this is served `\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003���T*K-*���S�RP2ԳP\br60U��\u0005\u0000k�%�\u001a\u0000\u0000\u0000`

Comment: See the additional info added to my post above.

Comment: i dont have control of the server hosting info.json

Comment: You seem to be doing something odd with the response - I can hit the URL and read the response as expected. I can also browse to it and view it. The incorrect responses shown above - I assume these are *after* you have retrieved it and spat it back out? If you *only* `console.log` the response from node, what does the console show?

Comment: I knw right? we can hit the url. I mentioned it at first in the question. but somehow curl and fetching it from node and serving it i get response like that. the `console.log` gives the same jibberish response as well.

Comment: i solved it using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636587/how-to-decode-gzip-or-utf-8-response-in-node. I did not see it at first. I dont know if it is efficient way

Comment: yeah i found a similar answer on mentioned link. Thanks anyway.

Comment: anyway, the answer is the answer you mentioned, so I have upvoted and selected your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(body.toString('ascii'))
```