# Access Body in Restify when GZip Encoded

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, restify

I am sending data in the body of a HTTP request to a Restify instance with a content-encoding of gzip. Only problem is I am unable to access the body with the gzipped data in it.

Here is my JS code that I am using to determine it, but req.body comes out as undefined:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
if(req.headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip')
{
    console.log(req);

    // We have a gzipped body here
    var zlib = require("zlib");
    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

    console.log("Body: "+ req.body)
    console.log("Length: " + req.body.length);
}
else
{
    apiKey = req.query['apiKey'];

    authenticateAndRoute(apiKey, req, res, next)
}
})
```

Anybody have a clue on how to access req.body here or an equivalent?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603029/1380486

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions of restify support this out of the box via the `bodyParser` plugin. You just need to initialise it like this:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
  bodyReader: true
}));
```

Request that have the `content-encoding` header with value `gzip` set will be automatically unzipped and the `req.body` will be parsed according to the indicated `content-type` header.