# Cannot print body of agario correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have encountered a weird problem I don't know how to fix. I use the following code to print the body of the response.

```
proxy_response.setEncoding('utf-8');
proxy_response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
});
proxy_response.on('end', function() {
    console.log('No more data in response.')
});
```

This code works fine with [this](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) website, but if I try it with [Agar.io](http://agar.io), it fails and prints a weird sequence of characters, even thogh the encoding is correct (According to the meta charset attribute of the response). I can view the correct source with chrome by typing `view-source:agar.io` into the search bar (This is what I would want my program to print). [This](http://pastebin.com/0FDt5K7g) is how the response looks like. [This](http://pastebin.com/vt8DCHu9) is the code I am confused about.

Comment: First, it sounds like you are up to no-good.  Second, you need to include all of your code for the creation of your proxy_response object so we can have a working example.

Comment: thanks @PrestonS for trying to help. I edited the question, I hope you can help :) the code: http://pastebin.com/vt8DCHu9

Comment: the weird thing is that it works for every other website I have tested, just not agario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agar.io's response is gzipped.

In the response headers you see:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603029/2464634) for how to unzip it.  Basically, pipe it to `gunzip`

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a lot of overnight debugging hours with lots of coffee. I'm such a derp.