# Why does this GET request seem to give random characters?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

This is 1 of my first times using the https node.js module and I tried to make a `GET` request with this code

```js
const url = new URL("valid url") //I did put a valid url

https.get({
    host: url.hostname,
    path: url.pathname,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding("utf8")
    let str = ""
    res.on("data", c => {
        console.log(c)
    })

    res.on("end", () => {
        console.log(str) //this was meant to log the data but I removed the "str += c" from the data callback
    })
})
```

But this logs the following:

```
▼�
�VJ-*�/��LQ�210ЁrsS��‼�S����3KR§2�§�R♂K3�RS�`J�↕sA�I�)�♣�E@NIj�R-��♥g��PP
```

But I would think `.setEncoding("utf8")` would work. Is it something to do with the headers? Or maybe the `URL` object? The result I want is in a `<pre>` element and is valid JSON.

Comment: You might want a higher-level library like `node-fetch`.

Comment: Can you show what the same request does with `curl` ? what does it actually return. Data is rarely ever random. It's probably some binary but hard to say with what you've shared so far.

Comment: curl? Is that another node.js package?

Comment: Either way - for all we know, your `valid url` is a random string generator. Also, you'll want to look at the response headers. If it says `content-encoding: gzip`, it's compressed...

Comment: @MrMythical no, it's a popular CLI tool to do HTTP requests. It will let you make a simple request and compare results.

Comment: This code logs what I want (a JSON object), but I want to see how to do it with the https package: `fetch(url).then(async val => { console.log( await ( val.json() ) ) })` and `fetch` is the `node-fetch` package

Comment: The content looks compressed.  I also suspect gzip.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207762/how-to-use-request-or-http-module-to-read-gzip-page-into-a-string)

Comment: @James looks like it was gzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889118/why-does-this-get-request-seem-to-give-random-characters?noredirect=1#comment123542355_69889118), the content was compressed. Doing this worked:

```js
import https from "https"

import { createGunzip } from "zlib"

const url = new URL("valid url")

const req = https.get(url, (res) => { //I found out you can use a URL object
    
    let str = ""
    let output;
        //See if it's compressed so we can read it properly
        var gzip = createGunzip()
        res.headers["content-encoding"] == "gzip" ? 
        output = res.pipe(gzip) :
        output = res;

    output.on("data", c => {
        str = c.toString()
    })

    output.on("end", () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(str || "{}")) //logs the correct object
    })
})
```